# How to transform SETOF into useful thing?

Tags: postgresql

`SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(0, 2)`  and `SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 2)` are useful, because returns columns and rows... Also `SELECT id,GENERATE_SERIES(0, 2) AS s FROM t`...

Now suppose a SETOF returning function like `json_each_text()`

```
SELECT * FROM json_each_text('{"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}'); -- OK, useful...    

SELECT id,json_each_text('{"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}') FROM t; -- Ops, UGLY THING!
```

So, how to "cast" the de second query to a util thing, with rows and coluns?

PS: the second query works fine but is not what I need (not is cols and rows).

---

Ops... I am solving (it works fine!) a very specific problem with (pg9.3+ feature)

```
SELECT t.id, key, value 
FROM t, LATERAL json_each_text(t.info);
```

but not understand how to solve the generic problem of "cast SETOF datatype" to rows and cols.

Comment: Check: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d197e/4/0 `SELECT t.id, key, value 
FROM t, LATERAL json_each_text(CAST(t.info AS JSON)); `

Comment: ops, sorry @lad2025  my table is `t(id INT, info JSON)` ... I used the quoted "cast" to refer SETOF.. The second query works fine (!), but it is ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, (json_each_text(t.info)).* FROM t
```